# Is this equation hard to solve?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve the equation below for $x$? $A$, $B$, $a$ and $r$ are constants.

\begin{equation}
  x + \frac{1}{1+Ar^{-x/a}} + B =0
  \end{equation}

Comment: I assume you meant to post this on the main site, not here on meta.

Comment: Instead of closing, I vote for migration to our main site.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I would've done that, but couldn't find the option. Did I just miss it, or can we no longer migrate posts to the main site from meta without bothering the mods?

Comment: How could i transfer the question to main site?

Comment: I don't think you can solve it analytically. But sure you can numerically, for given values of $a,A,B$ and $r$ of course.

Comment: @Ilmari: That's a job for the mods, I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: yes.

This equation is hard to solve (symbolically).

Even in the simple case
$$
x+\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}=0
$$
with solution $x \approx -0.401058137541547$, it is identified by the [ISC](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/) only as "solution of $z+W(z+1)=0$" where $W$ is the Lambert W function.